# How to save partial view's input in the save button of parent view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have some partial views which are entry form. The save button is in the Parent view. I want to save all the inputs from users through all partial views at a time using  a single "save" button in the parent view. How can I do that?

Comment: Partial views resolves at run-time to just an ordinary Html code so the question is more like : 'how do i get all data from html inputs on button click and store it somewhere?' . You can create JQuery script for this purpose.

Comment: Can I get all data from multiple Partial views and save it in the model of parent view? Can you provide the code?